# Object/Array manipulation

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

I'm getting an **array of objects** from a db query (nodejs, using Postgres w/ Knex) that looks like this: (minified version)

```
[ 
   {
    tvshow: 'house',
    airdate: 2017-02-01T00:00:00.000Z 
   },
   {
    tvshow: 'big bang theory',
    airdate: 2017-02-01T00:00:00.000Z 
   },
   {
    tvshow: 'simpsons',
    airdate: 2017-02-02T00:00:00.000Z 
   },
   {
    tvshow: 'suits',
    airdate: 2017-02-02T00:00:00.000Z 
   },
   {
    tvshow: 'sun',
    airdate: 2017-02-03T00:00:00.000Z 
   },
   {
    tvshow: 'blacklist',
    airdate: 2017-02-03T00:00:00.000Z
  },
  {
    tvshow: 'something',
    airdate: 2017-02-03T00:00:00.000Z 
  },
  {
    tvshow: 'homeland',
    airdate: 2017-02-03T00:00:00.000Z 
  },
  {
    tvshow: 'american dad',
    airdate: 2017-02-04T00:00:00.000Z 
  },
  {
    tvshow: 'games',
    airdate: 2017-02-05T00:00:00.000Z 
  }
]
```

The query that returns this, limits the **airdate** field to **5 days**. This means that whatever I do with it, it will **always have 5 days**.

My goal is to have the **tvshows filtered by day**.

**Expected output example**

```
{
    day1: [ 'house', 'big bang theory' ],
    day2: [ 'simpsons', 'suits' ],
    day3: [ 'sun', 'blacklist', 'something', 'homeland' ],
    day4: [ 'american dad' ],
    day5: [ 'games' ]
}
```

I've a working solution, but I think it could be improved. Here's what I'm doing atm. I'm using momentjs to compare dates. '**result**' is the name of the query result (array of objects).

```
const obj = {};
let array = [];
let i = 0;
let currentDate = null;

result.forEach((element) => {
  if (currentDate !== moment(element.airdate).format('DD-MM-YYYY')) {
    if (currentDate !== null) {      // skip first iteration where currentDate is null
      i++;
      obj[`day${i}`] = array;     // new day => store previous day tvshow's array in the object
    }
    array = [];     // reset temporary array
  }
  array.push(element.tvshow);    // push tvshow to temporary array
  currentDate = moment(element.airdate).format('DD-MM-YYYY');   // update current date
});
obj[`day${i+1}`] = array;    // add last/5th day array to the object
```

Comment: You haven't asked a question.

Comment: *"I've a working solution, but I think it could be improved."* Stack Overflow is primarily for questions about code that does *not* work. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ might be a better place for your question, but you need to be more specific still.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen sorry if I wasnt clear enough. the question is: 'Can this code be improved ? How ?'

Comment: @FelixKling thanks. I wasnt aware of codereview. I'll give it a try !

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to avoid modifying variables inside the `forEach` callback, that are defined outside of it.

Here is a version with `reduce`, which stores all state in the `reduce` accumulator. At the end, you can extract the part that contains the result object. It assumes that the dates are ordered in ascending order, which you can take care of in your query:

```
result = result.reduce( (acc, {tvshow, airdate}) => {
    acc.i += acc.airdate !== airdate;
    acc.airdate = airdate;
    acc.obj[`day${acc.i}`] = (acc.obj[`day${acc.i}`] || []).concat(tvshow);
    return acc;
}, {i:0, obj: {}} ).obj;
```

```js
let result = [ 
   {
    tvshow: 'house',
    airdate: '2017-02-01T00:00:00.000Z'
   },
   {
    tvshow: 'big bang theory',
    airdate: '2017-02-01T00:00:00.000Z' 
   },
   {
    tvshow: 'simpsons',
    airdate: '2017-02-02T00:00:00.000Z'
   },
   {
    tvshow: 'suits',
    airdate: '2017-02-02T00:00:00.000Z' 
   },
   {
    tvshow: 'sun',
    airdate: '2017-02-03T00:00:00.000Z' 
   },
   {
    tvshow: 'blacklist',
    airdate: '2017-02-03T00:00:00.000Z'
  },
  {
    tvshow: 'something',
    airdate: '2017-02-03T00:00:00.000Z' 
  },
  {
    tvshow: 'homeland',
    airdate: '2017-02-03T00:00:00.000Z' 
  },
  {
    tvshow: 'american dad',
    airdate: '2017-02-04T00:00:00.000Z'
  },
  {
    tvshow: 'games',
    airdate: '2017-02-05T00:00:00.000Z' 
  }
];

result = result.reduce( (acc, {tvshow, airdate}) => {
    acc.i += acc.airdate !== airdate;
    acc.airdate = airdate;
    acc.obj[`day${acc.i}`] = (acc.obj[`day${acc.i}`] || []).concat(tvshow);
    return acc;
}, {i:0, obj: {}} ).obj;

console.log(result);
```

I left out the formatting with `moment`, which is not the determining factor in this code. You can add it.

Comment: Thanks ! It looks way nicer. I have to take a look at the reduce function.